# How to get every record in a Recordset in VB?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Hey here my problems i'm calling a stored proc and I put the record into an ADODB RecordSet.
When i Check the field.count its say i got 6 result which is good. But when i try to loop into that record set it skips one of them. Heres my code

```
  oRs = g_oSQL.GetRecords("PS_palFetchAllPalette_sel")
        If Not oRs Is Nothing Then
            cmbPallet.Items.Clear()
            oRs.MoveFirst()

            While Not oRs.EOF
                If oRs.Fields.Item("palcode").Value.ToString() <> "None" Then
                    cmbPallet.Items.Add(oRs.Fields.Item("palcode").Value.ToString())
                End If
                oRs.MoveNext()
            End While
```

Comment: Stepping inside this code with the debugger will help you a lot to figure why a record is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what happens is when you reach your last record with oRs.MoveNext() then you are at EOF so next loop won't happen. try to change the structure of the loop.

```
With oRs
  Do Until .EOF
     'get your data
     .MoveNext

  Loop
```

End With

Comment: Never mind i've found the problem, I copi paste and part of my code from another program a mobile one that does exactly the same thing and it happen that what was missing doesnt have to appear in the mobile form of it

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with ADODB for a while but wouldn't field.count indicate the number of fields in the recordset and not the number of records returned? You could have returned 0 records but still have the metadata on the query.

Are you sure your check for "None" is working? This would require that palcode not ne empty or Null but have the actual value of "None." Set a breakpoint inside the While loop and see if your are getting what you expected.